# c++ dynamic allocation (pixel map)

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic-allocation

im new to both (memory allocation and classes)

im trying to make pixel map of (1 bit per pixel) so im trying to make 
char array in dynamic memory allocation..

```
class pixmap
{
private:
    char _rows;
    int _width, _height;
    char **pix_m;
public:
    pixmap(int , int);
    uint8_t getpixel(int, int);
    void printl(int);

};
```

so what im trying to do is for example if i wanted pixel map of (100 x 100) .. i allocate 2d array of char [100][1+100/8] .. where the char stores 8 bits

```
pixmap::pixmap(int width, int height)
{
    _width = width;
    _height = height;
    _rows = width/8+1;

    pix_m = (char**) (calloc(height,_rows));
    for (int x =0 ; x < _rows; x++)
    {
           pix_m[x] = (char*)calloc(_rows,sizeof(char*));
    }

    printf("%d\r\n",_rows);
}
```

this is my construct of the class ^^

and here where i should print a row of pixels:

```
void pixmap::printl(int y)
{
    int pix;
    for (int i = 0; i < _rows-1; i++)
    {
        for (int x= 0; x<8; x++)
        {
            pix = pix_m[y][i]&(0x01<<(7-x));
            printf("%d",pix!=0);
        }
    }
    int q = _width - (_rows-1)*8;
    for (int x= 0; x<q; x++)
    {
        pix = pix_m[y][_rows-1]&(0x01<<(7-x));
        printf("%d",pix!=0);
    }
}
```

and in main function :

```
int main()
{
    pixmap img(50,100);
    img.printl(1);

    getch();
}
```

the problem is when i try to print line bigger than 6 .. the program crashes .. shouldnt i be able to printl(0-99) ???

the code : 
http://pastebin.com/9X8r9PWe

Comment: it works but it crashes when im trying to (img.printl(7)) or more <<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usage of `calloc` function is wrong.

```
pix_m = (char**) (calloc(height,_rows));
```

This code does not work properly. As far as I can see you want `_rows` element vector of `char*`. It actually allocates height elements each of size equivalent to `sizeof(_rows)` thus `sizeof(char)` in your case. Instead you should invoke

```
calloc(_rows, sizeof(char*));
```

Your second call should be

```
pix_m[x] = (char*)calloc(height,sizeof(char));
```

EDIT: after analysing rest of your code it seems like you messed it up a bit and thus it should be:

```
pix_m = (char**) (calloc(height,sizeof(char*)));
for (int x =0 ; x < height; x++)
{
       pix_m[x] = (char*)calloc(_rows,sizeof(char));
}
```

Comment: hi .. thanks for your reply ..

i think calloc(_rows, sizeof(char*)); is same as calloc(_rows,1)

Comment: you right .. the problem was in the for loop 
for (int x =0 ; x < height; x++) <====== here u corrected it for me thx

Answer (score 1):

here i corrected the code :

```
class pixmap
{
private:
    char _cols;
    int _width, _height;
    char **pix_m;
public:
    pixmap(int , int);
    uint8_t getpixel(int, int);
    void printl(int);

};

pixmap::pixmap(int width, int height)
{
    _width = width;
    _height = height;
    _cols = width/8+1;

    pix_m = (char**) (calloc(height,sizeof(char)*_cols));
    for (int x =0 ; x < height; x++)
    {
           pix_m[x] = (char*)calloc(_cols,sizeof(char));
    }

    printf("%d\r\n",_cols);

    for (int i=0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<_cols; j++)
        {
            pix_m[i][j] = i;
        }
    }
}
```